# How can i filter bounces mail with date and time? [mailgun, laravel]

Tags: laravel, mailgun, laravel-mail

i am currently using **mailgun api /bounces** and i got bounces emails but it have all bounces emails no filter. But actually i want only last 1 hours bounces emails. How can i get like this?

Currently i am using

```
$response = Http::get('https://api:'
                    . env('MAILGUN_SECRET')
                    . '@api.mailgun.net/v3/'
                    . env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN')
                    . '/bounces');
```

I checked mailgun documentation. I didn't get any solution. Anyone help me to find out solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ***bounces api*** have list of bounces email so we can't filter for that. so if we want to filter then we use ***events api*** like below for above scenario.

```
        $end = Carbon::now()->toRfc2822String();
        $begin = Carbon::now()->subHour()->toRfc2822String();
        
        $response = Http::get('https://api:'
                            . env('MAILGUN_SECRET')
                            . '@api.mailgun.net/v3/'
                            . env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN')
                            . '/events', [
                                'event' => 'failed',
                                'begin' => $begin,
                                'end' => $end,
                                'ascending' => 'yes'
                            ]);
```

This way i solved my problem. I didn't get any answer for this question so that i add my answer it will help someone when face same issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is very useful as Mailgun's documentation is rather poor and it doesn't make it at all clear what the values of begin and end have to be. ie whether we are talking about a list of items sorted by date with the earliest arriving first or a stream of data with the last event arriving first.